# Eclipse angularjs-eclipse remove trailing space on save

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

I'm using `angularjs-eclipse` plugin, so the type of the project is angularjs, not javascript. So, autoremoving whitespace on save doesn't work even if activated in the settings. Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can create an issue at here https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't acheive that.

When you look at the preferences for the `AngularJS` type project in your eclipse, you can see that there is no `Save Actions` menu is available. This is perhaps the plugin's limitation (in terms of feature) as it only offers settings like "Syntax Coloring" and "Typing" (See screenshot given below)

[image: Preferences => AngularJS]

Where as if you look at the Javascript's preferences/settings, Since you have the "Save actions" you will obviously have the ability to change the "Remove trailing whitespace" upon save. (See snapshot below).

[image: Preferences => Javascript]

Perhaps you may try raising an issue at the GitHub URL as hurricane suggested in the comments.

Hope this helps!.